# Why PAGE_SIZE is often used in ioremap?

Tags: linux-kernel, page-size, ioremap

I often find ioremap just use **PAGE_SIZE** as its size like:

```c
drivers/spi/spi-orion.c:715:        dir_acc->vaddr = devm_ioremap(&pdev->dev, r->start, PAGE_SIZE);
drivers/gpu/ipu-v3/ipu-dmfc.c:182:  priv->base = devm_ioremap(dev, base, PAGE_SIZE);
drivers/gpu/ipu-v3/ipu-dp.c:338:    priv->base = devm_ioremap(dev, base, PAGE_SIZE);
drivers/gpu/ipu-v3/ipu-vdi.c:222:   vdi->base = devm_ioremap(dev, base, PAGE_SIZE);
drivers/gpu/ipu-v3/ipu-di.c:729:    di->base = devm_ioremap(dev, base, PAGE_SIZE);
```

Is it because it should map at least **PAGE_SIZE** even if its total length is smaller than **PAGE_SIZE**?

Comment: All virtual memory mapping is in units of the page size; that's how the hardware works.  So specifying a size smaller than one page wouldn't make sense.

Comment: The base and/or size do not need to be page-aligned. The `ioremap_prot` function called by `dev_ioremap` will make the necessary adjustments.